# I'm trying to nest if statement inside a while loop

Tags: python-3.x

I am building a hangman game as a beginner but i got stuck when i wanted the program to stop the loop if the number of correct guesses is equal to the length of the word. how do i stop the loop if the numbers are equal

here is the code:

```
    print (f'the first letter is {theww[0]}')
    chances = 5
    guesses = [theww[0]]
    newl = len(guesses)
    while chances != 0:
        choice = input ('Enter a word that you think is there: ')
        if choice in theww:
            print ('it is there')
            y = guesses.append(choice)
            print (guesses)
            if newl == length:
                print ('you won')
        elif choice not in theww:
            print ('not there')
            chances = chances - 1
        else:
            print('i think there was a problem, please start again')
            hangman()
    print('out of chances')
```

Comment: you can just add break in the condition where you want to break the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `break` right after you print `you win`.

Like this:

```
if newl == length:
    print ('you won')
    break
```

However, right now, when it breaks, it will print "out of chances" after "you win". To avoid this, put the "out of chances" in an else statement, similar to this:

```
    while chances != 0:
        choice = input ('Enter a word that you think is there: ')
        if choice in theww:
            print ('it is there')
            y = guesses.append(choice)
            print (guesses)
            if newl == length:
                print ('you won')
                break
        elif choice not in theww:
            print ('not there')
            chances = chances - 1
        else:
            print('i think there was a problem, please start again')
            hangman()
    else:
        print('out of chances')
```

The while/else makes sure that it will only print "out of chances" when the loop exits due to chances being 0. Check [this article](https://www.pythontutorial.net/python-basics/python-while-else/) out for more info.